# What are opensource frameworks for implementing network configuration for a network switch/router?

Tags: open-source, networking, configuration-management, snmp

We are implementing a simple router for a niche area and like to address the network configuration aspects a fresh view. I know of SNMP and netconf We like to have a good base framework and build other interfaces such as CLI, and WebUI on top of that. SNMP is must to have, since SNMP is legacy, many operators ask for it, even though they may not use it for configuration (may be used for traps and/or monitoring) Any insights?

Comment: Would [OpenWrt](https://openwrt.org/) help? I have had great fun programming [this](https://www.amazon.co.uk/GL-iNet-GL-MT300N-V2-Converter-Pre-installed-Performance/dp/B073TSK26W) - but, perhaps I misunderstand your question

Comment: @MawgsaysreinstateMonica: Thanks for the pointer. It seems rich ecosystem. I am not very sure if we can build upon using the framework, but I think this page is where I can start thinking about or see if we can leverage: https://openwrt.org/inbox/howto/opencpe?s[]=netconf . The thing is, SNMP is quite resource intensive and also not a right candidate to be in the bottom of the stack. I am looking to use a base (s/w) which can cater to SNMP or RESTful interfaces for device management.

Comment: Anything Linux based should have, or support, SMNP. I remember doing some SNMP message handling a few year sago, although I no longer remember the details. Good luck :-)